# Entity Framework Core : reference without relationship/navigation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following model - a `ProductLine` has many `PriceLists`.

I want to have a reference on the parent (`ProductLine`) that specifies the default `PriceList` from the child collection.

```
public class ProductLine 
{
     public virtual PriceList DefaultPriceList { get; set; }
     public virtual IList<PriceList> PriceLists { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PriceList>();
}

public class PriceList 
{
    public virtual ProductLine ProductLine { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add a migration I get this error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'PriceList.ProductLine' of type 'ProductLine'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

EF docs for references and navigation says:

> Multiple relationships cannot share navigations. Any foreign key can be associated with at most one navigation from principal to dependent, and at most one navigation from dependent to principal.

Does this mean this is simply not possible? Do I need to design the model such that the `PriceList` has a boolean `Default`? I can do this, but it changes the UI from the original application I am re-engineering.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you need to be explicit about the relationship, EF cannot infer it from two possible options:

- One-to-One:  Product.DefaultPriceList -- Priceline.Product
- Many-to-One: Product.Pricelists -- Priceline.Product

So you just need to tell EF which to use. The DefaultPriceList requires a FK of some sort either on Product or Priceline, though typically it would be on Product, something like DefaultPriceListId. This could either be a mapped FK, or a shadow property. As a shadow property there are 3 ways to wire it up, either a `[ForeignKey]` attribute in the entity, the DbContext.OnModelCreating handler, or having it load a configuration class extending `IEntityTypeConfiguration`

Attribute:

```
 [ForeignKey("DefaultPriceListId")]
 public virtual PriceList DefaultPriceList { get; set; }
```

ModelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasOne(x => x.DefaultPriceList)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Product>("DefaultPriceListId");
```

Then in the model builder ensure that it knows that the PriceList.Product goes back to the "many" relationship for Product.Pricelists:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasMany(x => x.PriceLists)
    .WithOne(x => x.Product)
```

... and that should sort out the ambiguity.

Note that for normalization there is a bit of a problem with this structure in that there is no inherent way to enforce that for a Product, the DefaultPriceList actually references a PriceList associated to that Product. You could set a DefaultPriceListId value to a PriceList associated with a different Product. You should also place a unique constraint on Product.DefaultPriceList to help guard this. It would ensure that a PriceList can only be a default for one Product, though alone it doesn't ensure it is the default for the correct Product. You may want to consider adding an SQL job on the DB to run periodically to inspect the relationships and alert you if it finds any occurrances where a DefaultPriceListId on a Product row points to a PriceList with a different ProductId.